# I want to read that XML file and store it into the local strings variable in c++

Tags: c++, xml

Can anyone help me in how to do this in c++ programing ? an also please provide some useful links to learn how to program for reading XML through C++ in windows.

Comment: Check this out: http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/

Comment: Do you just want to load the file as a string (as suggested by the title), or are you trying to _parse_ the XML as an XML file?

Comment: Can you edit your answer to give a simple example of the XML fil that you are trying to parse and the expected local string variables you'd like to see? Upvotes if you show your own attempt!

Answer (score 3):

An easy library for reading / writing XML is [tinyxml](http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxml/). It's a very practical tool, widely-used.

Answer (score 0):

Use libxml2 it's very easy to work on Handling Xml files

http://xmlsoft.org/tutorial/index.html

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in the title if you just want to load the file to a String :

```
ustring data;
char line[1000];
memset(line, 0, 1000);
char *retVal = NULL;
while ((retVal = fgets(line, 1000, incomingFileHandle)) != NULL)
{
    data += line;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way for a beginner to read (parse) XML, is to use MSXML DOM  [A Beginner's Guide to the XML DOM](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa468547.aspx) and sample code [Parsing an XML file in a C/C++ program](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/XML/ParsingXMLFile.aspx), SAX or XmlLite: [XmlLite Samples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752864%28v=VS.85%29.aspx). You can use other libraries for XML handling, such as Xerces: [Xerces, Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xerces).